# Different kernel versions across different machines

Tags: kernel, updates

I have 2 different machines, with the same OS version, and the same sources list.

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I update my packages using the following commands on `pc-1` and `pc-2`:

```
$ sudo apt update
<...>
$ sudo apt -y upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

However, I get different kernel versions for each machine:

```
pc-1 $ uname -r
5.0.0-25-generic
```

and

```
pc-2 $ uname -r
4.15.0-58-generic
```

Why is that, and how can I safely update `pc-2` to the latest generic kernel using official repos and not ppas ?

Is there a way to debug/print the kernel selection logic in apt ?

Comment: Instead of editing the question body you should either post an answer of your own, edit the accepted answer to include that information or comment the accepted answer to let the author do it for you. Question bodies shouldn't contain answers...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 either upgraded from a prior release (17.10 or 16.04 LTS) or installed with the original ISO, or 18.04.1 ISO uses the standard kernel 4.15.

Ubuntu 18.04.2 and later ISO installs default to using the HWE or hardware-enablement stack kernel, ie. the kernel upgrades to using 18.10's kernel, then 19.04 (5.0 is the current 19.04 kernel being used), then 19.10 kernel, before finally settling on the 20.04 kernel.

The HWE kernel can also be selected as an option for older 18.04/18.04.1/upgraded-to-18.04 machines too.

One of your machines uses HWE kernel, one does not.

> Installing the HWE stack is simple:
>
> DESKTOP
>
> `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`
>
> SERVER
>
> `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04`

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack